# sqlMessage: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" Node-MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to simply insert data into my MySQL database, table which I am trying to insert has an ID column with primary key and auto-increment and an email. I am generating random emails from the faker npm package. While I followed the documentation properly the console is showing the error message stated above. What should I do to make it correct? I guess there is something wrong with the auto-increment column.
here is my server.js code:

```
const myFaker = require("faker");
const mysql      = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : "",
  database : "test"
});

function emailGenerator(){
    const emails =[];
    for(i=0; i<500;i++){
        emails.push(myFaker.internet.email());
    }
    console.log(emails)
    return emails;
}
var data = [emailGenerator()];
var q = 'INSERT INTO node (email) VALUES ?';
connection.query(q, [data] ,function(error,results,fields){
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(results);
})
connection.end()
```

My SQL query to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE node (
            id INT(25) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            email VARCHAR(25) 
            );
```

The error message:

```
  code: 'ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW',
  errno: 1136,
  sqlMessage: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",
  sqlState: '21S01',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO node (email) VALUES ('Shayne.OConner45@yahoo.com', 'Willy.Romaguera30@gmail.com', 'Reece.Dickens@gmail.com', 'Alberto66@hotmail.com', 'Edna_Kozey@yahoo.com'......
```

Comment: It is because either you have not provided the sufficient ```?``` in the query corresponding to the number of cols or you have unwanted cols as parameter in the query function

Comment: @SrinathKamath I don't get what you actually meant, would you please elaborate?

Comment: @SrinathKamath I assume I am following the syntax of bulk insertion, if I did not had an additional column (the ID one with the auto-increment) then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in emailGenerator function, use the following code to push new emails

```
emails.push([myFaker.internet.email()])
```

Comment: still doesn't work the error message is like:sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''(Rafael11@hotmail.com,Shaun_Botsford52@hotmail.com,Logan.Skiles73@hotmail.co...' at line 1",

Comment: I have changed the answer, try it. also you will have to modify your table VARCHAR(25) is too short for the email set it to 255